# Using Turbo in Ruby on Rails app that was updated from 5.2 to 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-7

recently I updated the legacy `Ruby on Rails` application from version `5.2` to `7.0`.
I want to use `Ruby on Rails 7.0` features like Turbo etc.

Can I use `turbo-rails` gem with `sprockets` Asset Pipeline?
I'm having there  a lot of legacy javascript so try to avoid if possible updating  to  the `import-maps`  approach.

Thanks in advance